# How to run an plain java app on Websphere

Tags: java, jar, websphere

I have a standalone java application which has one main class. I want to run this class when Wepsphere starts up. I don't want to use servlet for this.
How can I do this using admin  console/scripting etc?

Thanks

Comment: What does the class do? Does it need to run inside of Websphere (or just when the server starts up, for example as an external process)?

Comment: Java class will start Thrift server which will invoke webservice deployed on Websphere. Thrift is basically bridge between webservice and php client. Communication over thrift will be done on sockets

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit hacky, but I'd be tempted to add a line to `startServer.{bat|sh}` to start your Java program.  E.g. (on Windows):

```
start "Thrift" /D<working directory> java -cp <classpath> com.thrift.Main
```

If you need to stop the program again when Websphere is shut down, you might want to edit `stopServer.{bat|sh}` as well.

**Alternatively...** *(and preferably)*

Create a new script that starts both your app and Websphere, and run that instead:

```
start "Websphere" /D<was-working-dir> startServer.bat
start "Thrift" /D<thrift-working-dir> java -cp <classpath> com.thrift.Main
```

Advantage is that you don't end up editing the Websphere scripts, so you won't be affected by any changes that future WAS patches might apply.  However, if WAS is being started as a service, then you might need to alter the command that's being run to point to your new script instead.  As with most of the rest of this answer, how to do this differs depending on your platform.

Comment: I wouldn't do this. As long as the OP can't describe *why* he wants to do this, I'd discourage him.

Comment: Java class will start Thrift server which will invoke webservice deployed on Websphere. Thrift is basically bridge between webservice and php client. Communication over thrift will be done on sockets.

Comment: @Tichodroma You're probably right, but I find it immensely irritating when I ask "How?" and people say "Don't!". Sometimes I really do have a good reason! Having said that, not sure it's true in this case - surely more sensible to have a script which starts both Thrift and Websphere and use that...

Comment: If I want to run Thrift and Websphere on same JVM (websphere) then what would be right approach?